# Erase function in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Can someone tell me what the following lines do

```
else if ( obj < retrieve() ) 
{
    return ( left() == 0 ) ? 0 : left()->erase( obj, left_tree );
} 
else 
{
    return ( right() == 0 ) ? 0 : right()->erase( obj, right_tree );
}
```

in the code block below:

```
    template <typename Comp>
    int Binary_search_node<Comp>::erase( Comp const &obj, Binary_search_node<Comp> *&ptr_to_this) 
{
    if ( obj == retrieve() ) {
        if ( leaf() ) { // leaf node
            ptr_to_this= 0;
            delete this;
        } 
        else if ( left() != 0 && right() != 0 ) { // full node
            element= right()->front();
            right()->erase( retrieve(), right_tree );
        } 
        else { // only one child
            ptr_to_this= ( left() != 0 ) ? left() : right();
            delete this;
        }
        return 1;
    } 
    else if ( obj < retrieve() ) {
        return ( left() == 0 ) ? 0 : left()->erase( obj, left_tree );} 
    else {
        return ( right() == 0 ) ? 0 : right()->erase( obj, right_tree );}
}
```

Extra Information:

1)

```
front() -- finds the minimum objects
```

Implementation:

```
template <typename Comp>
Comp Binary_search_node<Comp>::front() const 
{
    return( left() == 0 ) ?retrieve() :left()->front();
}
```

2)

```
left()  -- returns pointer to left subtree
```

3)

```
right() -- returns pointer to right subtree
```

4)

```
*ptr_to_this points to current object (same location as what *this points to)
```

---

---

I have an idea of what the lines do, but I am not 100% sure thus I wanted to confirm. Please note that this `erase()` function is for a binary search tree. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what element is?

Comment: element is the obj stored inside the node of a B-search tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`erase` appears to be implemented recursively.  At each stage, we test whether the object to erase is equal to the current object, or whether we need to go down into the left or right child.

If the child that we want to go into does not exist (`left() == 0` or `right() == 0`), then we cannot erase the object (because it's not in the tree), so we return `0`.  Otherwise, we recurse into the child function, and return whatever it returns.

Answer (score 3):

Those lines are simply performing the search for the item you want to delete.  In english it would read:

- If the value to delete is less than the current value, then try to go left.
- If the value to delete is
  greater than the current value, then 
  try to    go right.
- If the node you are trying to go to does not exist, then return 0.

Comment: I thought if the current value is less THEN it should go RIGHT since right sub-tree contains numbers greater than current number and left sub-trees actually contain numbers smaller than current. =S Could you explain why it seems to be doing the opposite?

Comment: Sorry, the response wasn't that clear... I tried to clarify it a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Your code searches the binary tree (and assumes its elements are sorted) for `obj`, and if it recursively finds it, deletes it and returns `1`. If it doesn't find it, it will return `0`.